# VBA stop running auto

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code has been working perfectly in Excel for a long time, but now suddenly has stopped refreshing automatically. Can someone help to point out what could the reason for such change?

Many thanks

```
Sub AutoRefresh(when As Date)
    Application.OnTime when, "Save_Attachment_GFI"
End Sub

Sub Save_Attachment_GFI()
    
    Dim Olook As Outlook.Application
    Dim OMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ONameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Fol As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim TimeStart, TimeEnd
        
    TimeStart = TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
    TimeEnd = TimeSerial(10, 30, 0)
            
    Set Olook = New Outlook.Application
    Set OMailItem = Olook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set ONameSpace = Olook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fol = ONameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Fol = Fol.Folders("FFA")
    Set FolItems = Fol.Folders("FFA GFI").Items
     
    FolItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    
    Set OMailItem = FolItems(1)
    
    For Each Atmt In OMailItem.Attachments
        Atmt.SaveAsFile "C:\" & Atmt.Filename
    Next
        
    If Dir("C:\") <> "" Then
        Kill ("C:\")
    End If
            
    If Dir("C:\") <> "" Then
        Kill ("C:\")
    End If
    
    If Dir("C:\") <> "" Then
        Kill ("C:\")
    End If
        
    If Time > TimeStart And Time < TimeEnd Then
        AutoRefresh Now + TimeSerial(0, 2, 30)
    Else
        If Time < TimeStart Then AutoRefresh Date + TimeStart
        If Time > TimeStart Then AutoRefresh (Date + 1) + TimeStart
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug it with F8 and see the exact moment *it stops*

Comment: Could it be with what triggers the above code? I had similar on code that was supposed to run on `Workbook_Open` event, but when opened from a new computer that didn't trust the file, the workbook open event didn't trigger.

Comment: Debugging returns no error, hence I am a bit stuck here. Happy for any help.

Comment: If I go in an start the code manually, it all works. But it dont start over again, so it is something with the trigger of the code, but cant see whats wrong unfo